# Difference between __new__ and __init__ order in Python2/3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, metaclass

In Python 3, if any value that is not an instance of `cls` is returned, the `__init__` method is never called. So I can, for example, do this:

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar(n):
        return n * 5

    def __new__(cls, n):
        return Foo.bar(n)

print(Foo(3))  # => 15
```

I was under the impression that the order was `__call__` (if it's an instance) -> `__new__` -> `__init__`.

However, in Python 2, this seems to raise a `TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments` due to the lack of an `__init__`. I can fix that by inheriting from `object`. So, running this:

```
class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("new called")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("init called")

Foo()
"""
Python2: "init called"
Python3: "new called"
"""
```

In Python 2, I even messed around with metaclasses.

```
Meta = type("Meta", (type,), dict(__call__=lambda self, x: x * 5))

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

print(Foo(4))  # => 20
```

But this does not work in Python3 because the init/new methods seem to be reversed.

Is there any Python2/3 compatible way of doing this?

## Solution:

This is the way I did it. I don't like it, but it works:

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def __call__(i):
        return i * 5

    def __new__(cls, i):
        return Foo.__call__(i)
```

Surely there is a more pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2, you need to use new-style classes to make classes work properly.  That means you need to define your class as `class Foo(object)`.  Then your first example will work in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Damn beat me to it but verified this is why.

Comment: That was too easy. Thanks!

Comment: @Goodies: What behavior?

Comment: `__new__` is not called with Pyrhon2.

Comment: @Goodies: I don't think `__new__` is called for old-style classes at all.  Like many features of Python classes, it only works for new-style classes.